# Getting a 502 Proxy error for POST route form to mysql db

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, proxy

**After filling out a form on my live website, I get this message in the browser when I hit submit:**

Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /contact.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at (mysite) Port 80

**ubuntu error log:**

Mon Jan 22 00:12:21.518850 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 18331:tid 139839210997504] [client 24.245.70.116:62084] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /contact, referer: (myurl)

**.conf file:**

```js
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.(mysite).net
    <Location "/">
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3210/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3210/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
~
```

Comment: What are you posting? How is MySQL a factor here?

Comment: The site works until I try to submit a form into my database(mysql)

Comment: What form? From where? To what? This question is talking about the HTTP layer with zero context.

Comment: a form asking for name, email, message and when I hit submit the error I mentioned comes up.  I know the query is correct.

Comment: "A form" is not a helpful description of the form in question. If you can't give specifics this question will be closed. We're not psychic. We don't know what you've done. We don't know what you're trying to do. We don't know *anything* until you can explain in more specific details. Please, try and understand from our point of view. We can only work with what we're given.